# What's wrong with the code of the equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image]

I tried this code below but it does not execute and I couldn't find out what is wrong in the equation. What did I do wrong?

```
$MDAC(t_{i,j}) = max_{ti}\epsilon pred(t_{j})(C_{i,j)$
```

Comment: I think we're all dying to know what `MDAC` is? :P

Answer (score 11):

Your primary problem is with `(C_{i,j)`, which should be `(C_{i,j})`, in other words, you have not paired all your delimeters, you need a closing brace. You should have received the error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
```

More generally I would recommend:

```
$MDAC(t_{j}) = \max_{t_{i} \in pred(t_{j})}(C_{i,j})$
```

Or perhaps you want?

```
\newcommand{\pred}{\operatorname{pred}}

$MDAC(t_{j}) = \max_{t_{i} \in \pred(t_{j})}(C_{i,j})$
```

[image]

According to others, `MDAC` is a single unit. It is probably better, therefore, to treat it as an operator and set it upright, but suppose you want it set in italics, you can have:

```
$\mathit{MDAC}(t_{j}) = \max_{t_{i} \in \pred(t_{j})}(C_{i,j})$
```

Which will improve the spacing between the letters, treating `MDAC` as one unit, rather than the product of four separate variables `M`, `D`, `A` and `C`. For upright typesetting follow Bernard's advice or what I have done with `\pred`:

```
\newcommand{\MDAC}{\operatorname{MDAC}}
\newcommand{\pred}{\operatorname{pred}}

$\MDAC(t_{j}) = \max_{t_{i} \in \pred(t_{j})}(C_{i,j})$
```

[image]

Comment: "MDAC" should be entered either as `\mathrm{MDAC}` or as `\mathit{MDAC}`. Entering it as `MDAC` induces TeX to typeset it as if were a collection of four separate variables named `M`, `D`, `A`, and `C`.

Comment: @Mico thanks, fair enough, I'm genuinely unfamiliar with `MDAC` so I left it alone, for all I knew, it is the product of the three variables `M`, `D` and `A` with `C(t_{j})`. But I'll edit, although it makes my answer functionally indistinguishable from Bernard's ...

Comment: Well, you can choose the `\mathit` method to make your solution look different from Bernard's. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think `MDAC` and `prec` should be typed in italics. I suggest considering them as `maths operators`, like `log`, `sin`, &c., to ensure a correct spacing w. r. t.  possible exponents, indices or delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MDAC}{MDAC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pred}{pred}

\begin{document}

 $ \MDAC(t_{i,j}) = \max_{t_i\in \pred(t_j)}(C_{i,j}) $ %

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is "MDAC" an operator or the name of a variable? If it's the latter, it's probably better to define `\newcommand\MDAC{\mathrm{MDAC}}`.

Comment: @Mico: I wondered. I opted for an operator because it was followed by a pair of parentheses. Maybe the O.P. will tell us.